# Rails SQL query, passing array of ids to sql WHERE...IN clause

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

Dealing with a HABTM relationship and need to write a sql query string that I can run via `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(my_query)`

A SQL WHERE...IN clause expects an array of integer ids, something like this: `"DELETE from contacts_tags where tag_id = 99 AND contact_id IN (1, 2, 3, 4)`

I have an array of the ids I want to pass into the IN clause, but can't seem to format it in a way that SQL will accept.

```
ids_for_delete = [1, 2, 3, 4]
my_query = "DELETE from contacts_tags where tag_id = 99 AND contact_id IN (#{ids_for_delete})"
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(my_query) 
    #=> There is an error in your SQL syntax.
```

What is the proper way to pass a array of ids to a SQL WHERE clause?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try:

```
my_query = "DELETE from contacts_tags where tag_id = 99 AND contact_id IN (#{ids_for_delete.join(', ')})"
```

use the method join to generate string like "1, 2, 3, 4.."

Comment: Thanks! I must have been overthinking it.

Comment: when `ids_for_delete` is blank, it's going to break

Comment: @rony36 you will need to detect the array first, make sure it's not blank before you use this express.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use ANY operate with array values:

```
DELETE FROM contacts_tags WHERE tag_id = 99 AND contact_id = ANY('{ #{ids_for_delete.join(",")} }'::int[])
```

It will not break even if you pass an empty array.